# SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis 00906. 00000 - "missing left parenthesis"

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE customer(customer_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY
, customer_name VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
, customer_address VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL
, customer_email VARCHAR2(35)
, customer_number NUMBER (11) NOT NULL CHECK LENGTH(customer_number) = 11)
```

This is just taking the mick I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: what happens if you start excluding components?

Comment: BTW: this is the reason that `DOMAIN`s exist. IIRC Oracle has domains, while Microsoft does not have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying a constraint name, and I believe that you need to have the check constraint in brackets:

```
, customer_number NUMBER (11) NOT NULL 
  constraint custnumlen CHECK (LENGTH(customer_number) = 11))
```

Take a look at http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php